# How do i copy every line X line from a bunch of files to another file?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep, cat

So my problem is as follows:
I have a bunch of files and i need only the information from a certain line in each of these files (the same line for all files).
Example:
I want the content of the line 10 from file example_1.dat~example_10.dat and then i want to save it on > test.dat

I tried using: `head -n 5 example_*.dat > test.dat`. But this gives me all the information from the top till the line i have chosen instead of just the line.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ for f in *.dat ; do sed -n '5p' $f >> test.dat ; done
```

This code will do the following:

Foreach file f in the directory that ends with .dat.
Use sed on the 5:th row in file and write to test.dat.
The ">>" will add the row at the bottom of the file if existing.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `head` and `tail` to zoom to the needed line. For example, `head -n 5 file | tail -n 1`

You can use a `for` loop to get it done over several files

```
for f in *.dat ; do head -n 5 $f | tail -n 1 >> test.dat ; done
```

PS: Don't forget to clean the `test.dat` file (`> test.dat`) before running the loop. Otherwise you'll get results from previous runs as well.

Comment: I works but its too heavy (i have tons of text files). I need something that works the way the head -n 5 example_*.dat > test.dat (he gets all the info first, concat all of them and then saves it to the file i choose). I will work with this for now anyway, thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer to contain the `for` solution for multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` or `awk`:

```
sed -n "5p"

awk "NR == 5"
```

Comment: I dont know how to use it so i get the information from all the files and then save it to a new one (like the head code i wrote does). This way i only get the line from one document.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -sn '5wtest.dat' example_*.dat
```